# Solve matrix equation A*X=X*B using LeastSquares

Tags: equation-solving, linear-algebra

I want to solve matrix equation `A*X=X*B` using LeastSquares method, but it is suited for equation like A*X=B.

All matrices are 3x3

```
A = {{a11, a12, a13}, {a21, a22, a23}, {a31, a32, a33}}

B = {{b11, b12, b13}, {b21, b22, b23}, {b31, b32, b33}}

X = {{x11, x12, x13}, {x21, x22, x23}, {x31, x32, x33}}

a33=b33=x33=1, a31=0,a32=0.
```

How can I do this?

**Update:** 
I figure out that it's special type of equation

I'm trying to solve a special case of [Sylvester equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation)
in my case it looks like 
$$A*X=X*B$$
so it can be write in form 
$$A*X+X*(-B)=C$$  where C consist of all 0 items.

I tried to solve it in Mathematica with [LyapunovSolve](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LyapunovSolve.html)
but it gives me a all-zero trivial solution.

So I want to check if a non-trivial solution exists. It seems I find out how to test matrices A,B for non-trivial solution (but I'm not sure) if resultant equals to 0, then such solution exist.$$\mathrm{resultant}(\mathrm{det}(A-λE),\mathrm{det}(B-λE),λ)=0$$  I tried real matrices for example `A = {{0 -1 300}, {1 0 0}, {0 0 1}}`, `B = {{-0.4009 -1.0787 446.1463}, {1.6180 0.8875 -159.2272}, { 0.0003 0.0029 1}}` but there is maybe a problem because B matrix was defined experimentally and it has some small errors, with these matrices I have resultant -6.79 , but due to erorrs I don't know may be it close enough to 0?

My question is:
Can you write condition of existence of non-trivial solution of Sylvester equation not in abstract form but in particular formula, preferably in Mathematica.

Also I don't understand why Mathematica gives me only trivial solution, when I try to solve this equation with parameters. For example I tried

```
am = {{a11, a12, a13}, {a21, a22, a23}, {a31, a32, a33}}

bm = {{b11, b12, b13}, {b21, b22, b23}, {b31, b32, b33}}

cm = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}

LyapunovSolve[am,bm,cm]
```

which gives me all 0. Also I tried to multiply matrices and get 9 equations and solve them with function Solve which also give me all 0.

Comment: You haven't said anything about the dimensions or special features of your $A$, $B$, and $X$ (assuming they're matrices). What is your **actual** problem?

Comment: @j-m A,B,X are matrices 3x3 and in matrix A last row is 0 0 1, and in matrices B,X last elements =1. A is rotation matrix, B,X is perspective transform matrices. here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9106/solve-non-linear-system-of-equation-in-mathematica how I try to solve this problem in other way.

Comment: I don't have time to write something up, but you might want to look into Procrustes transformations.

Comment: @j-m I don't understand how it can help.

Comment: Also I find out that equations like A*X=X*B can be solved like this http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LyapunovSolve.html http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation but it gives me all =0 for my matrices.

Comment: So I want to check if there is bo trivial solution exist. It seems I find out how to test matrices A,B for non-trivial solution if resultant(det(A-λE),det(B-λE),λ) equals to 0, then such solution exist.I tried real matrices for example A matrix (0 -1 300 1 0 0 0 0 1) B matrix (-0.4009 -1.0787 446.1463 1.6180 0.8875 -159.2272 0.0003 0.0029 1) but there is maybe a problem because B matrix was defined experimentally and it has some small errors, with these matrices I have resultant -6.79 , but due to erorrs I don't know may be it close enough to 0?

Comment: @mrgloom You need not using `LeastSquares`  to solve your equation, since it yields vectors, not matrices. If `A`,`B`,`X` are the given matrices, one can use e.g. `Reduce[A.X == B.X, {a11, a12, a13, a21, a22, a23, b11, b12, b13, b21, b22, b23, b31, b32, x11, x12, x13, x21, x22, x23, x31, x32}]`.

Comment: @Artes if I specify a(i,j),b(i,j) as numbers Reduce give me False, if as parameters it works too long and I don't know when it finishes.

Comment: That Sylvester equation is for when A, B are known and X unknown.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau yes this is my case I want to find X.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is to get you started towards your strategy (using LeastSquares methods).
One can put your equation `A*X-X*B=C` in the form `D*Xp=Cp`, where `Xp, Cp` are vectors containing the entries of `X, C` respectively.

```
a = {{a11, a12, a13}, {a21, a22, a23}, {a31, a32, a33}};
b = {{b11, b12, b13}, {b21, b22, b23}, {b31, b32, b33}};
x = {{x11, x12, x13}, {x21, x22, x23}, {x31, x32, x33}};

eqs = Flatten[Dot[a, x] - Dot[x, b], 1];

xp = Flatten[x]

(* {x11, x12, x13, x21, x22, x23, x31, x32, x33} *)

d = Outer[Coefficient[#1, #2] &, eqs, xp]

(* {{a11 - b11, -b21, -b31, a12, 0, 0, a13, 0, 0}, 
    {-b12, a11 - b22, -b32, 0, a12, 0, 0, a13, 0}, 
    {-b13, -b23, a11 - b33, 0, 0, a12, 0, 0, a13}, 
    {a21, 0, 0, a22 - b11, -b21, -b31, a23, 0, 0}, 
    {0, a21, 0, -b12, a22 - b22, -b32, 0, a23, 0}, 
    {0, 0,  a21, -b13, -b23, a22 - b33, 0, 0, a23}, 
    {a31, 0, 0, a32, 0, 0, a33 - b11, -b21, -b31},
    {0, a31, 0, 0, a32, 0, -b12, a33 - b22, -b32}, 
    {0, 0, a31, 0, 0, a32, -b13, -b23, a33 - b33}} *)
```

Example (from [help](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LyapunovSolve.html?q=LyapunovSolve&lang=en) on `LyapunovSolve`) :

```
a = {{-1, 1, 0}, {-1, -1, 1}, {1, 1, 0}} ;
b = {{-2, 0, 0},{0, -1, 0},{0, 0, -3}} ;
cMat = -{{Subscript[c, 1], 0, 0}, {0, Subscript[c, 2], 0},
         {0, 0, Subscript[c, 3]}};

eqs = Flatten[Dot[a, x] + Dot[x, b], 1];
xp = Flatten[x];
cp = Flatten[cMat];
d = Outer[Coefficient[#1, #2] &, eqs, xp];

Dot[Inverse[d], cp]

(* { (5 Subscript[c, 1])/16, Subscript[c, 2]/2, Subscript[c, 3]/46, 
    -(Subscript[c, 1]/16), Subscript[c, 2], (2 Subscript[c, 3])/23, 
      Subscript[c, 1]/8, (3 Subscript[c, 2])/2, (17 Subscript[c, 3])/46} *)

LyapunovSolve[a, b, cMat]

(* {{(5 Subscript[c, 1])/16, Subscript[c, 2]/2, Subscript[c, 3]/46}, 
    {-(Subscript[c, 1]/16), Subscript[c, 2], (2 Subscript[c, 3])/23}, 
    {Subscript[c, 1]/8, (3 Subscript[c, 2])/2, (17 Subscript[c, 3])/46}} *)
```

Comment: "One can put your equation A*X+X*B=C in the form D*X=C"


          the problem is that can't be done (or not so simple).

Comment: @mrgloom Could you explain why the above is incorrect ?

Comment: maybe I don't understand how Outer works, but what we have in the output? 9 posible equations D*X=C?

Comment: @mrgloom Please see edit.

Comment: I still don't understand, what is output "d" and how it can be used?

Comment: @mrgloom Added example.

Comment: now I understand that it's equivalent to LyapunovSolve, but how i wrote it gives me all=0 if C matrix consist of all=0. And I think that Dot[Inverse[d], cp]  gives me all=0 if cp=0.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. I tried to write matrix equation A*X-X*B=0 [3x3]*[3x3] as matrix equation as new_A*new_X [9x9]*[9*1] and solve it with LeastSquares it also goves me all=0, even if A matrix is numerical and B matrix is params. maybe mathematica not suitable for this?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. From the wikipedia article you cited above: "the Sylvester equation has a unique solution if and only if A and -B have no common eigenvalues". Therefore, for C=0 and if this condition is true, you will always get X=0. Is the condition fulfiled for your matrices A,B?

Comment: @sebhofer and how to test that "A and -B have no common eigenvalues" ?

Comment: @mrgloom See this [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix#Simultaneous_diagonalization). Checking if the two matrices commute may not be completely trivial if they consist of floating point numbers. My first approach would be `PossibleZeroQ`...